# Is it possible to go to a random function in python?

Tags: python

I've been working on a game, and I'm trying to go to random functions. Here's my code:

```
import random


def choice1():
  print("This is in choice 1 right now.")


def choice2():
  print("This is in choice 2 right now.")


def choice3():
  print("This is in choice 3 right now.")  


room_list = [choice1, choice2, choice3]
new_room = random.choice(room_list)
```

Just calling the variable doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't `new_room()` work?

Comment: RaySteam is right, just call new_room()

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`random.choice(room_list)` returns a function, you still have to call it:

```
import random


def choice1(): 
    print("This is in choice 1 right now.")

def choice2(): 
    print("This is in choice 2 right now.")

def choice3(): 
    print("This is in choice 3 right now.")

room_list = [choice1, choice2, choice3]
new_room = random.choice(room_list)()  # note the () to call the function
```

Sample output:

```
This is in choice 2 right now.
```

Comment: Just to note, a temporary variable can make this easier to read; `chooser = random.choice(room_list); new_room = chooser()`. The lone `()` at the end is easy to lose sight of in a chain.